# ASP.Net Core Identity Pages throws 404 error after deploying to server but work fine hosting in local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

Once after hosting the project both in local IIS and in server, I found that in server all the identity related pages throws 404 error, whereas in local IIS it works fine. All the other pages apart from Identity Pages are accessible. My StartUp class looks like this:

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
        new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));


        var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(true);

        });
        //services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<XonetPlus_V3.Entities.Domain.User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();




        services.AddDataProtection()
 .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
 .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        });



        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        services.AddTransient<IRepositoryWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        IdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=admindashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            // endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("queryParams", "{controller=admindashboard}/{action=Index}/{param}/{id}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areas", "{area:exists}/{controller=admindashboard}/{action=Index}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: First enable logging to get more proper error message and check this path you have in your code.
services.AddDataProtection()
 .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))..

Comment: Other Pages I am able to access. But Identity Pages--> No webpage was found for the web address: http://159.122.70.249/Identity/Account/Login
HTTP ERROR 404